# Div Not Aligned For IE Only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a simple one page static site with a bootstrap container div wrapping 4 other divs.

the "intro-box" class element should be centered. it is perfectly centered in firefox and chrome.  However IE11 positions it at the far left of the container div. Ive included the html and css. any help much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "my_title" %></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "my_description" %>">

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
 <%= favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= yield(:head) %>
</head>
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
<div class="background">
<%=image_tag("bkgrnd.jpg", :class=>"background-img")%> 
</div>
  <div class="container">   
    <div class="center-div">
<div class="social">
     some social networking stuff
    <div class="email-capture">
   some fields to capture users emails
    </div>
     <p class="intro-box"> some introductory stuff </p> 
    </div>
  <div class="opaque-block"> some stuff</div> 
     </div>      
  </div>
```

CSS

```
 .intro-box{
  left: 0; right: 0;
  position:absolute;
   top:185px;
   display:block;
  margin:auto;
  font-family: "abeatbyKai", sans-serif;
  color:#000;
  max-width:180px;
 height:90px;
  padding:10px;
 }
```

Comment: have you tried removing the position:absolute and left:0,right:0? it should center it without those.

Comment: cant believe it was that simple but it worked. I had to set its position to relative. Not sure why it would on chrome and firefox but thanks anyways. If you submit your response as an answer ill mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the  left:0,right:0
and set position to relative from absolute.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing left, right and absolute position as said by JanR, add margin as

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

if you don't want top, bottom margin and to make it uniform across browsers, as you have specified the max-width the margin will automatically align it to center, or for IE you can just remove

```
position: absolute
```

i tried it it's working

Answer (score 0):

Try this... you may need to adjust the margin of 185px to fit your needs.

```
.intro-box{
   margin:185px auto 0 auto;
   display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family: "abeatbyKai", sans-serif;
  color:#000;
  max-width:180px;
  height:90px;
  padding:10px;
 }
```